# How to start static session d-bus and assign its value to environmental variable

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, systemd, dbus

Anyone know how to start static session d-bus using system (.service) file?.

I want that session address should be assigned to an environmental variable.

Comment: Looks like you want something like https://serverfault.com/questions/892465/starting-systemd-services-sharing-a-session-d-bus-on-headless-system.

Comment: No.actually in the above link, session dbus is created using user service.But I want to create using system service.

Comment: That’s a contradiction in terms. You can’t have a session bus run by the system, because the system has no session to run it in.